# How to code so the program finds multiple instances - Python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
Words = ['python','candy', 'banana', 'chicken', 'pizza', 'calculus',
     'cheeseburger', 'binder', 'computer', 'pencil', 'school'
     'artist', 'soccer', 'tennis', 'basketball', 'panda',
     'zebra', 'horse', 'cereal', 'alphabet', 'understand']

number = raw_input('Enter a 1 through 20: ')
x = list()
find = list(Words[int(number)-1])
notherword = list(Words[int(number)-1])
l = list(len(find)*'_')
print 'Your word is', len(find)*'_ '
playing = True
while playing:
    letter = raw_input('Please pick a letter ')
    if letter in find:
        a = find.index(str(letter))
        l[int(a)] = letter
        q = (' ')
        j = q.join(l)
        print j
        find[a] = ('_')
        if l == notherword:
            print 'You win!!!'
            playing = False
    else:
        print 'Strike ' +str(len(x)+1) +str('.') +str(' Not a letter in the word')
        x.append(letter)
        if len(x) > 4:
            print 'Game Over x('
            playing = False
```

This is a hangman game. You first pick a number then that number corresponds with the word and starts a game of hangman. But when i do the word banana it only finds the first a and does not find the other a's. How do I code so that it can find multiple instances at the same time so that it runs through fine??

Edited with newer code

Comment: Your code, as pasted here, is broken: its indentation is wrong. Could you repair it?

Comment: sorry which part it seems fine

Comment: The big red flag is that the line below 'if letter in find:' is not indented.

Comment: That is the point: I do not know which part is broken because the error can be in a lot of places :) Copy-and-paste the code above and run it, you'll see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace this

```
if letter in find:
    a = find.index(str(letter))
    l[int(a)] = letter
```

with this

```
letter_in_word = False
for a,c in enumerate(find):
    if c == letter:
        l[a] = letter
        letter_in_word = True
if letter_in_word:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Comment: this code still goes through the else part. i thinkk its because the code is running through each and every letter and finds that for example the n and such is not a therefore it runs through the else

is there a way to not do this

Comment: @jimbob, I changed my answer to set a flag if the letter is in the word

Comment: wonderful. but one glitch. it only finds two a's in banana and doesnt find the third one

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to replace the found letters with something else, so they can't be found twice. You could grab all the indexes of a given letter using a list comprehension:

```
if letter in find:
    # use a list comprehension to get the index of all occurrences of a given letter
    indexes = [i for i, char in enumerate(find) if char == letter]
    # update found and l accordingly
    for i in indexes:
        find[i] = None
        l[i] = letter
```

And then to check if they've won, you can instead do:

```
if '_' not in l:
    print 'You win!!!'
```

You'll also want to create `x` outside of the `while` loop, instead of recreating it every time a player guesses wrong, so the player can actually lose (you can also do `while True` and break, instead of using the `playing` variable):

```
x = list()
while True:
    ...
    else:
        print 'Not a letter in the word'
        x.append(letter)
        if len(x) > 4:
            print 'Game Over'
            break
```

As an aside, you don't need to use `str` or `int` in the loop. Also `''.join()` is a common Python idiom, you should use that instead. Here's a revised version, taking the above into consideration:

```
Words = ['python','candy', 'banana', 'chicken', 'pizza', 'calculus',
     'cheeseburger', 'binder', 'computer', 'pencil', 'school'
     'artist', 'soccer', 'tennis', 'basketball', 'panda',
     'zebra', 'horse', 'cereal', 'alphabet', 'understand']

number = raw_input('Enter a 1 through 20: ')

find = list(Words[int(number)-1])
l = list(len(find)*'_')
x = list()

print 'Your word is', len(find)*'_ '

while True:
    letter = raw_input('Please pick a letter ')
    if letter in find:
        indexes = [i for i, char in enumerate(find) if char == letter]
        for i in indexes:
            find[i] = None
            l[i] = letter
        print ' '.join(l)
        if '_' not in l:
            print 'You win!!!'
            break
    else:
        print 'Not a letter in the word'
        x.append(letter)
        if len(x) > 4:
            print 'Game Over'
            break
```

Comment: but if i remove the letter then the index numbers change and the program screws up

Comment: But in this case the index of the next letter would be wrong, no? The new call of index would return the index of the next a in the word `bnana`.

Comment: I kind of modified your (zeekay) idea and made it so that it would have two lists of the same word and replace each letter it found. it worked but it didnt find multiple instances. for banana i had to type in a three different times

Comment: Oh you are right, I didn't read through your code completely. I updated my answer with a simple approach.

Comment: Sorry, guess I don't know how to play hangman. I updated my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a loop to match each a in turn:

```
while playing:
    letter = raw_input('Please pick a letter ')
    while letter in find:
        a = find.index(letter)

        # Clear the letter so we can match the next instance.
        find[a] = None 

        l[a] = letter
        q = (' ')
        j = q.join(l)
        print j
        if l == find:
            print 'You win!!!'
            playing = False
    else:
        ....
```

[ It's not all that commonly done, but you can use else with while in Python. ]

Also, you should set x = list() above the game loop, as it stands, you will never lose.

Comment: I've tried something similar to this with a for loop. It's doing the same thing it did with the for loop it does find multiple instances but it runs through the else part as well as printing out the j the number of times the letter is in the word.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
a = find.index(str(letter))
l[int(a)] = letter
```

Try this

```
[l.__setitem__(pos, letter) for pos in range(len(find)) if find[pos]==letter]
```

Basically, it iterates over the word sets the letter at the position to be the chosen letter if the chosen letter is at that position in the word that needs to be found.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't normally just write the code for someone, but sometimes it's the best way to illustrate various techniques. Please study closely. Note that if I were actually writing this code, it wouldn't have any of those comments; these techniques are standard.

```
# Let's wrap the "main" code in a function for cleanliness.
def main():
    words = [
        'python','candy', 'banana', 'chicken', 'pizza', 'calculus',
        'cheeseburger', 'binder', 'computer', 'pencil', 'school'
        'artist', 'soccer', 'tennis', 'basketball', 'panda',
        'zebra', 'horse', 'cereal', 'alphabet', 'understand'
    ]
    import random
    word = random.choice(words)
    # Instead of using a list of characters for what's been
    # guessed, a string will work fine. We can iterate over it
    # the same way.
    guessed = '_' * len(word)
    failures = '' # used to be 'x'. Use descriptive names.

    # To break out of a loop, we can use the 'break' keyword.
    # So we don't really need a separate variable to control the loop.
    # We want to show status every time through the loop, so we put that
    # inside the loop.
    while True:
        print guessed
        # Note the idiomatic way we use to intersperse spaces into the word.
        print 'Not in the word:', ' '.join(failures)
        letter = raw_input('Please pick a letter: ')
        # We use the following trick to update the guess status:
        # 1) We'll create a second string that contains the guessed
        # letter in each place where it should appear.
        # 2) If that string differs from the old guess, then we
        # must have guessed a letter correctly. Otherwise, the letter
        # is not in the word.
        # We take pairs of letters from `word` and `guessed` using the
        # zip() function, and use the letter from the word if it's matched,
        # and otherwise keep the letter from the old guess. `''.join` joins
        # up all the chosen letters to make a string again.
        new_guess = ''.join(
            w if w == letter else g
            for (w, g) in zip(word, guessed) 
        )
        if new_guess == word:
            print 'You win!!!'
            break
        elif new_guess != guessed:
            print "Yes, '%s' is in the word." % letter
        else:
            # Instead of having the ugly '+1' in the logic for counting misses,
            # just count the misses *after* processing this one. Also note how
            # the string formatting works.
            failures += letter
            print "Strike %d. '%s' is not in the word." % (len(failures), letter)
            if len(failures) > 4:
                print 'Game Over x('
                break
```